# Keycloak: Add custom extension io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension

Tags: keycloak, wildfly

I wanted to add a custom servlet extension to Keycloak which would install a http handler that gets invoked on every request sent to Keycloak and sets up some logging MDC context that our custom SPI code can use for logging the incoming request traces correctly.

Following the docs [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow#servlet_extensions) I created a custom extension class:

```
public class UndertowHandlerExtension implements ServletExtension {
    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, ServletContext servletContext) {
        deploymentInfo.addInnerHandlerChainWrapper(TraceIdCapturingHandler::new);
    }
}
```

And have defined my custom http handler `TraceIdCapturingHandler`  in the same JAR file. I also added a file to `META-INF/services/io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension` and set the fully qualified reference to the extension class. I also updated my deployments `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and added the following 2 entries as dependencies:

```
      <module name="io.undertow.servlet" />
      <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
```

However, when my deployment is created the extension is not being invoked and my filter is not executing. Is there something I am missing in terms of how to configure Wildfly for Keycloak so that my extension and handler are installed and used correctly?

EDIT:

After doing a bit of digging I realized I was headed down the wrong path. Looked at [this](https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi) repository and I think I need a custom RealResourceProvider as shown [here](https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/aerogear/keycloak/metrics/MetricsEndpointFactory.java) which in turn can install my filter by obtaining an instance of `ResteasyProviderFactory` and invoking `getContainerRequestFilterRegistry().registerSingleton()`.

Will try this out and report back.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want to do?  Based on what I read it sounds like a simple servlet filter or ContainerRequestFilter / ContainerResponseFilter, none of which requires a module.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for your response - you are right about not needing a module. please see my edit above for the question and let me know if the approach makes sense? Is implementing a RealmResourceProvider and adding the filter in the `init()` method an appropriate thing to do? Or should I use some other Keycloak SPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the edit above for my question. I was able to implement a RealmResourceProviderFactory instance that initialized the filters I needed on startup in the `init()` method:

```
    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {
        log.info("Initializing");
        initializeKeycloakFilters();
    }

    private void initializeKeycloakFilters() {
        ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
        TraceIdCapturingFilter filter = new TraceIdCapturingFilter();
        providerFactory.getContainerRequestFilterRegistry().registerSingleton(filter);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did anyone manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I need to implement a filter to capture all requests coming into the backend of KC version 23.0.6. In the log I noticed that it was started, but the filter does not occur, some configuration is missing?

log

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-45) KC-SERVICES0047: global-filter-extension (XX.XXX.keycloak.filter.GlobalRequestResponseFilterResourceProvider) is implementing the internal SPI realm-restapi-extension. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
2024-02-21 19:01:29,416 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 7817ms
```

in the service folder

[image]

```
public class GlobalRequestResponseFilter  implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    protected static final GlobalRequestResponseFilter INSTANCE = new GlobalRequestResponseFilter();

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        log.info("Before request: request: {}", requestContext);

        KeycloakSession keycloakSession = Resteasy.getContextData(KeycloakSession.class);
        KeycloakContext context = keycloakSession.getContext();


//        String traceId = requestContext.getHeaderString("X-TraceID");
//        MDC.put("traceId", traceId);

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        log.info("After request: request: {} response: {}", requestContext, responseContext);
//        MDC.remove("traceId");
    }
```

GlobalRequestResponseFilterResourceProvider.class

```
@AutoService(RealmResourceProviderFactory.class)
@Slf4j
public class GlobalRequestResponseFilterResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

    private final GlobalFilterResourceProvider INSTANCE = new GlobalFilterResourceProvider();

    private static final String PROVIDER_ID = "global-filter-extension";

    @Override
    public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
        log.info("________________________________________ INIT________________________________");
        GlobalRequestResponseFilter globalRequestResponseFilter = new GlobalRequestResponseFilter();
        ResteasyProviderFactory resteasyProviderFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
        resteasyProviderFactory.getContainerRequestFilterRegistry()
                .registerSingleton((ContainerRequestFilter) globalRequestResponseFilter);

        resteasyProviderFactory.getContainerResponseFilterRegistry()
                .registerSingleton((ContainerResponseFilter) globalRequestResponseFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }


}
```